# Vb.net number truncate. How to do this?

Tags: vb.net, numbers, rounding

I wanna round "2.765467..." number to "2.70".
How can i do that?

İ tried Math.round or math.floor but not working:(

Anyone can send a code for vb.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is truncate, not round.  Try this:

```
Dim decTemp = (10 ^ NumberOfPlaces)
Return CDec(Fix(ToTruncate * decTemp) / decTemp)
```

Where `ToTruncate` is the number you'd like to truncate, and `NumberOfPlaces` is the number of decimal places you want to truncate to.  In your case:

```
Dim ToTruncate As Decimal = 2.765467D
Dim NumberofPlaces as Integer = 1
Dim decTemp = (10 ^ NumberOfPlaces)
Return CDec(Fix(ToTruncate * decTemp) / decTemp)
```

Comment: +1 because it works - I thought there might be a more intuitive approach (but I couldn't think of it either).

Comment: @DaveDoknjas -- Yeah, I just had this in my snippets.  So I must have come across this at some point and tried to find a better approach like you.

Comment: sorry but Return CDec(Fix(ToTruncate * decTemp) / decTemp) saying to me wrong :( Edit: its done but "2.7" showing. i need "2.70" :(

Comment: İts done :)         TextBox1.Text = Format(TextBox1.Text, "standard") i used this for "2.70" thx to you soo much

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ToTruncate As Decimal = 2.765467D
        Dim NumberofPlaces As Integer = 1
        Dim decTemp = (10 ^ NumberofPlaces)
        TextBox1.Text = CDec(Fix(ToTruncate * decTemp) / decTemp)
    End Sub